# Wireless ESP32 Game Controller Build Issue

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, esp32

I'm building a wireless ESP32 game controller. For other parts, I am using an Adafruit #3886 accelerometer, a Cellevia Batteries 1850mAh Li-Po battery and a Sparkfun Electronics Li-Po Charger Plus PRT-15217. At first I thought I could build the circuit in a way where the battery is only connected to the charger, which is then connected to the ESP32, which is of course connected to the accelerometer. However, I started wondering if the battery could still provide power to the ESP32 through the charger if the charger isn't connected to an external power source (not the battery). I can't seem to find that out from the charger's documentation. If this wouldn't work, it would basically mean that I can't use the game controller wirelessly. I've tried looking this up everywhere and can't seem to find an answer. I would also be open to other, potentially better build solutions.

Documentation for the Li-Po charger: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/b/a/7/6/8/MCP73833Datasheet.pdf?_gl=1*n1g2gc*_ga*MTM2MTI0MTIxNi4xNjk4Nzg1ODI1*_ga_T369JS7J9N*MTY5ODgwMDk2My4zLjEuMTY5ODgwMTIyMS42MC4wLjA.